# JavaScript putting two variable's value into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, input

i have two variables `name` and `location` which are provided by two `<input type="text">`. I need to get an outcome of `Smith_California` but I am getting an output of `userName_userLoca` in the console.

Any suggestions would help.

currently, I have:

HTML:

```html
<form class="inputContainer" id="inputContainer" methed="post">
  <label for="userNam">Your Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="userNam" id="userNam" name="userNam" />
  <label for="userLoca">Your Location</label>
  <input type="text" class="userLoca" id="userLoca" name="userLoca" />
  <button class="vButton" id="vButton" type="submit" onclick="testfun()">
    Begin Test
  </button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```js
var userName = document.getElementById('userNam');
var userLoca = document.getElementById('userLoca');
var userSID = ['userName', 'userLoca'];
console.log(userSID.join('_'));
```

Comment: I don't understand what you did with the edit other than how I used tab or 2xspace. please explain for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing dom-element, using **var userName = document.getElementById('userNam');**.
Try with var userName = document.getElementById('userNam').value.
Also remove the quotes from *var userSID = ['userName', 'userLoca'];* and use it like below
**var userSID = [userName, userLoca];**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes and use `.value`:

```
var userSID = [userName.value, userLoca.value];
```

Comment: ahh it's that simple